# While loop causes unwated latency while activating a TENS Machine for a limited time

Tags: unity-game-engine, while-loop, arduino

Hi I have a Unity video game controlled using a flex sensor - when the user flex's their bicep the character moves forward. I want to activate a TENS machine when the user collects certain objects in the game. I have this working.....the problem is I want to activate the TENS machine for 1000ms and then deactivate it. I can activate/deactivate the TENS machine from the game engine via the serial port my issue is with the DELAY function. When I use the DELAY function it causes a glitch or pause in the game play....as a work around I tried using the function below, it would activate the TENS but it would not deactivate it.

```
#include <elapsedMillis.h>
#define interval 1000
elapsedMillis timeElapsed;

void triggertens()
{
 digitalWrite(TENS, HIGH);
 if (timeElapsed > interval) {
 timeElapsed -= interval; //reset the timer
 digitalWrite(TENS, LOW);}  
 }
```

What does work is a WHILE LOOP however this also causes a glitch similar to the DELAY:

```
void triggertens()
                   {
                      elapsedMillis timeElapsed;
                      while (timeElapsed < interval)
                      {
                      digitalWrite(TENS, HIGH);
                      }
                      digitalWrite(TENS, LOW);
                      timeElapsed = 0;  
                    }
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: It's important to avoid blocking operations on the main gameplay thread, as any delay over a few milliseconds may cause the game to stutter or freeze. I don't know the API you're working with, but you may need to see if it's possible to use some event-based or other asynchronous message passing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Unity to work with a "threaded" type feel that doesn't block the main execution you will need to use a coroutine.  Unity is all run on a single thread so any line of code that you write will need to finish executing before running the next line.  It looks like you are using c or c++ code for your delay function and having that wait a certain amount of time, however if you call that from unity the function wont return until the time is done waiting on that same thread (therefore making the game appeared paused).

In order to do this you will need to have your delay occur in Unity using a coroutine and tell the plugin you are using to turn on and off from the Unity side of the code, not from the plugin code.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html